# selected color of MaterialToggleButton to a solid color

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, android-togglebutton

Not able to make the selected color of MaterialToggleButton to a solid color, only a transparent shade of color primary is shown.

I tried the below set of code and the out image is shown below.

Button theme in styles

```
 <style name="ThemeButtonColorToggle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorOrange</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorOrange</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/colorOrange</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">@dimen/mtrl_btn_stroke_size</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorOrange</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimarySurface">@color/colorOrange</item>
    </style>
```

XML code

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:checkedButton="@id/btnAndroid"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAndroid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeButtonColorToggle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorOrange"
            android:text="Android" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btniOS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeButtonColorToggle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="iOS" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

I require to get a solid color as shown below

[image]

can anyone please help me to sort out

Comment: The background color of the buttons is defined by the backgroundTint attribute (without the android prefix) but you can't change this with the android:theme. You have to use the style attribute in the xml layout.

Answer (score 12):

The background color of the MaterialButton is defined by the `backgroundTint` attribute.

The [default value](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector.xml#L18) is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

You can change it in the xml layout or you can define a custom style:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
           style="@style/ButtonStyle"
           .. />
```

with:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/your_button_background_selector</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: I created new selector with state_checked="true" gave it a highlighted color and it worked. Thanks!