# Change the background color of MaterialButtonToggleGroup

Tags: android, material-design, android-togglebutton, materialbutton

I'm using MaterialButtonToggleGroup to create selector buttons.
I want to change the background color of MaterialButton buttons. Its default color is light blue, and I want to change it to light green. Currently, I'm using drawable sectors to change the background color, but it is not working.

**Default color**,
[image]

**Want this color,**
[image]

**Here is my layout,**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedButton="@id/btnOutline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnOutline"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="@string/outline"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMain"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

**Here is my drawable file "button_selector",**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selector_color"/>

</selector>
```

**Here is the "selector_color" file,**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#93cdcb"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: This seems directly related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558058/selected-color-of-materialtogglebutton-to-a-solid-color

Answer (score 4):

For material button you should use app:backgroundTint instead of android:background
Android documentation also mentions it here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton

> Do not use the android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages
> its own background drawable, and setting a new background means
> MaterialButton can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it
> introduces will function properly
>
> For filled buttons, this class uses your theme's ?attr/colorPrimary
> for the background tint color and ?attr/colorOnPrimary for the text
> color. For unfilled buttons, this class uses ?attr/colorPrimary for
> the text color and transparent for the background tint.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by using `android:state_checked="true"`instead of `android:state_selected="true"` in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting it to '**android:background**' you could try setting the selector on the '**android:backgroundTint**' property. If you want to update the border-color consider updating and '**app:strokeColor**'

Answer (score 0):

**Create MaterialButton  programatically**

```
    MaterialButtonToggleGroup grupo = new MaterialButtonToggleGroup(this, null, com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
    MaterialButton btn1 = new MaterialButton(this, null, com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
    btn1.setText("Ejemplo 1");
    //here 
    btn1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
    btn1.style
    grupo.addView(btn1);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76210687/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).